# How can I have multiple labels the same size within Auto Layout programmatically?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

Imagine the following layout within a `UITableView`. The red area is a `UILabel` and the blue area is a `UITextField`.

[image]

I have the following constraints to get me started:

```
    var allConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    allConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textFieldLabel!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.textFieldLabel!.superview, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    allConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textFieldLabel!, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.textFieldLabel!.superview, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    allConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.textFieldLabel!, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    allConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField!, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.textField!.superview, attribute: .trailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    allConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField!, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.textField!.superview, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(allConstraints)
```

However the outcome is not desired. The red label takes all of the whitespace. I am having a lot of trouble grasping how auto-layout works can anyone help me out here?

*EDITED 6 APR 2017*

When I add content hugging with the following line `self.textFieldLabel!.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh, for: .horizontal)` I will get the following result. As you can see somehow the labels get cut off.

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using a `UIStackView`? That would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Share screenshot of what you get.

Answer (score 2):

At a glance your constraints look reasonable and I suspect what you're missing is the content hugging priority of your label and text field. Content hugging defined how important it is that the intrinsic content size of a view match the minimum required to fit it's contents.

As is both views probably have the same content hugging priority (the default of 250) and that leads to an ambiguous layout. The intrinsic content size of your labels will be whatever width is required to fit your text. The intrinsic content size of your empty text field will be 0. Your constraints require that these two views together span their entire superview but since it is equally important for them both to hug their content their are two valid layouts:

1. The label is only as wide as needed and the text field fills the rest of the space.
2. The text field is only as wide as needed and the label fills the rest of the space.

You're seeing layout #2 but that could switch at any time because there's no way to reliably choose which content hugging size takes precedence since they have the same priority.

You could fix this by increasing the content hugging priority of your labels. If the content hugging priority of your label is greater than the priority of your text field then it is unambiguous which view should grow first to fill the available space; i.e. we're telling autolayout that it is more important to keep the view with the higher content hugging priority small.

See [Anatomy of a Constraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html) for more.

Comment: An example would be useful: textFieldLabel?.setContentHuggingPriority(251, for: .horizontal)

Comment: Yes you are correct layout #2 is occurring. When I set content hugging the labels get cut off see screenshot in my updated question.

Comment: @Mark That is due to setting textField leading equal to textFieldLabel trailingMargin. The margin is inset, so is causing textField to overlap.
allConstraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textField!, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.textFieldLabel!, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

Answer (score 0):

UILabels have an *intrinsic size*, basically meaning if you **only** define leading/trailing anchors to adjacent controls, their widths will be automatically adjusted to only fit the content inside it.

[Apple Doc on Intrinsic Size.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html)

One way you can do what you want is to set an explicit width for each UILabel.

Another way (nearly the same) is to set the width for one UILabel and set the remaining UILabel left/right anchors to the first UILabel's left/right anchors.

There's likely more - including using UIStackViews, etc., but since you already have most of your auto layout done, the first two are the easiest.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I should create a table view cell where I put a UIStackView in with horizontal flow that has the UILabel and UITextField am I correct?